# Do channels which do not affect a subsystem always have the form $\mathcal E=\mathcal T_{\mathcal A}\otimes\text{id}_B$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

consider a bipartite state on two Hilbert spaces $\rho_{AB}$. Usually, I think of a channel $\mathcal E$ as acting only on $A$ if

$$\mathrm{Tr}_A(\mathcal E(\rho_{AB}))=\mathrm{Tr}_A(\rho_{AB}) \tag A$$

i.e., the action of the channel on a system does not influence the reduced state on the other system. My question is: is this equivalent to

$$\mathcal E=\mathcal{T_A}\otimes\mathrm{id}_B$$

where $\mathcal T_A:A\rightarrow A$?

That the second line imples the first is obvious, the other direction doesn't look obvious to me, there could be some action on $B$ that somehow gets canceled by taking the trace somehow. Is it true?

Comment: I think this question is similar to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/434702/how-do-we-know-that-if-only-rho-a-evolves-then-the-evolution-of-rho-ab?rq=1 but I did not really understand the answer

Comment: @StarBucK You're right! It's very similar. The answer is pretty long, I will read it when I have time and report back, thanks!

Comment: @Noiralef No, I mean $\mathrm {Tr}_A$, the equation means that the "remaining" state on $B$ when we trace $A$ away is not affected by a channel acting only on $A$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An simple argument goes via the [Choi-Jamiolkowski isomorphism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270032/whats-the-intuition-behind-the-choi-jamiolkowski-isomorphism):

The Choi state is obtained by applying the channel to the left half of a maximally entangled state,
$$
\vert\Omega\rangle = \sum_{ij} \vert i,j\rangle_{AB}\vert i',j'\rangle_{A'B'}\ .
$$
The Choi state is then
$$
\sigma_{\mathcal E}= (\mathcal E_{AB}\otimes I_{A'B'})\,(\vert\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega\vert)\ .
$$
Now consider the channel you describe above, namely $\mathrm{tr}_A\circ \mathcal E$.  Its Choi state is $\chi=\mathrm{tr}_A\,\sigma$.  On the other hand, your equation (A) tells us that
$$
\mathrm{tr}_A\,\sigma = \chi = \rho_{A'}\otimes \vert\omega\rangle\langle\omega\vert_{BB'}\ ,
$$
where $\vert\omega\rangle = \sum_i \vert i\rangle_B\vert i\rangle_{B'}$ (since (A) says that $\mathrm{tr}_A\circ \mathcal E$ acts as the identity channel on $B$. This implies that $\sigma$ must be of the form
$$
\sigma = \rho_{AA'}\otimes \vert\omega\rangle\langle\omega\vert_{BB'}\ ,
$$
which is the Choi state of a channel of the form
$$
\mathcal T_A\otimes I_B\ .
$$

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to prove that (A) implies that the Kraus operators $A_a$ of $\mathcal E$ are local, that is, they have the form $A_a=\tilde A_a\otimes I$. For the purpose, I will leverage here the representation of the channel in terms of an enlarged unitary, and use it to prove the result on the Kraus operators.

### Enlarged unitary representation

Every map CPTP $\mathcal E$ can be written as $\newcommand{\ketbra}[1]{|#1\rangle\!\langle #1|}\newcommand{\calU}{{\mathcal{U}}}\newcommand{\calE}{{\mathcal{E}}}\newcommand{\calH}{{\mathcal{H}}}\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}\calE(\rho)=\tr_E[\calU(\rho\otimes\ketbra{0_E}) \calU^\dagger]$ for some (unique) unitary $\calU$.
Explicitly, denoting with $K(\calE)$ the natural representation of $\calE$, the relation between $\calE$ and $\calU$ can be written as
$$K(\calE)_{ij}^{k\ell} = \sum_a \calU_{ia}^{k0} (\calU^*)_{ja}^{\ell0}.$$
Feel free to completely ignore the placement of up/down indices, I only do it to make the formula a bit easier to read.
If this looks similar to the Kraus decomposition of the channel, that's not a coincidence. The relation between the unitary $\calU$ and the Kraus operators $A_a$ is $(A_a)_i^k = \calU_{ia}^{k0}$.

While the above notation is for maps acting on a single system, the formulae translate seamlessly to a bipartite scenario by "duplicating" each index: $i\to(i_1,i_2)$, $j\to (j_1,j_2)$ etc.

### What (A) implies for $\mathcal U$

Note that if (A) holds for all states $\rho_{AB}$, it holds in particular for all pure product states $|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle$. On these states, $\calU$ must act in such a way that tracing out the subsystem $A$ still gives a pure state on $B$ (because $\tr_A(\ketbra\psi\otimes\ketbra\phi)=\ketbra\phi$ is pure). We must thus have

$$
  \calU\, |\psi\rangle_A|\phi\rangle_B|0\rangle_E = |\Psi_{AE}\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle_B,
$$
where $|\Psi_{AE}\rangle$ is some state in $\calH_A\otimes\calH_E$ (the joint space of $A$ and the auxiliary space $E$).
More explicitly, this expression reads
$$
  \calU_{ima}^{kn0} \psi_{k}\phi_n = \Psi_{ia} \phi_m.
$$
If we choose $|\psi\rangle,|\phi\rangle$ to be elements of the computational basis, we conclude that
$\calU_{ima}^{kn0} = \delta_{nm} \Psi^k_{ia}$, where $\sum_{ia}\Psi^k_{ia}|i,a\rangle$ is some pure state in $\calH_A\otimes\calH_E$ for each $k$. Now all that remains is to see why this implies the original statement  about the form of $\calE$.

### Conclude that $\mathcal E$ is local

We proved that the Kraus operators of $\calE$ have the form
$$(A_a)_{im}^{kn} = \delta_{mn} \Psi^{k}_{ia} \Longleftrightarrow
A_a = \tilde A_a\otimes I$$
for some set of operators $\tilde A_a$ acting on $\calH_A$.
This is enough to prove the statement: a map is local if and only if its Kraus operators are. If we want to be more explicit, we can write the expressions componentwise as:
$$
\calE(\rho) =
\sum_a A_a \rho A_a^\dagger
\Longleftrightarrow (\calE(\rho))_{im,jn} = (A_a)_{im}^{k\ell} (A_a^*)_{jn}^{pq} \rho_{k\ell,pq}
= \Psi^k_{ia}(\Psi^*)^p_{ja}\rho_{km,pn}.
$$
We can then define the operator $\mathcal T$ with components
$$(\mathcal T)_{ij}^{kp} = \sum_a \Psi^k_{ia}(\Psi^*)^p_{ja},$$
and observe that $\calE = \mathcal T\otimes I$.

***TL;DR***: Consider the action of the map on pure product states, and observe that (A) implies that its Kraus operators are local.

Comment: Just a technical question: you are saying that if the partial trace of $\rho_{AB}$ is a pure state then $\rho_{AB}$ must have been a pure product state. Is it easy to see why that is true?

Comment: that is not true, a counterexample is $\rho_{AB}=\rho\otimes |1\rangle\!\langle 1|$. What I'm saying (if I understand what you are referring to) is that if the partial trace of a *pure* state $|\Psi_{AB}\rangle$ is pure, then the state must have been a (pure) product state $|\Psi_{AB}\rangle=|\psi_A\rangle\otimes|\psi_B\rangle$. To see it, compute the Schmidt decomposition of $\Psi_{AB}$. If it's not a product state, there are multiple Schmidt coefficients, and thus the partial state is not pure

Comment: Thank you, in the end I accepted the other answer as it was a more concise argument, but this was helful as well!